# Vaadin 8 Horizontal layout with Label and Button

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I am using Vaadin 8 to create header with label and button on right corner.
I want to display a header with format "Label                 |Button".

The problem is I am unable to align the button to right corner. Appreciate if anyone could give some pointers

Here is the sample code snippet.

```
    CssLayout menuItemsLayout = new CssLayout();
    menuItemsLayout.setPrimaryStyleName("valo-menuitems");
    menuItemsLayout.setWidth("100%");

    HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    horizontalLayout.setWidth("100%");

    Label headerLbl = new Label(
            "Please click on '+' to create a new Note.");
    headerLbl.setSizeUndefined();

    Label filler1 = new Label(" ");
    filler1.setWidth("100%");

    Button addNoteHeaderBtn = createAddViewButton("Add Note", "", CommonUiUtils.addIcon);
    addNoteHeaderBtn.setStyleName("btnRight");
    addNoteHeaderBtn.setSizeUndefined();

    horizontalLayout.addComponent(headerLbl);
    horizontalLayout.addComponent(filler1);
    horizontalLayout.addComponent(addNoteHeaderBtn);

    horizontalLayout.setExpandRatio(filler1, 1.3f);

    menuItemsLayout.addComponent(horizontalLayout);

    mainVerticalLayout.addComponent(menuItemsLayout);

private Button createAddViewButton(final String name, String caption, Resource icon) {
        Button button = new Button(caption, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            }
        });
        button.setPrimaryStyleName(ValoTheme.MENU_ITEM);
        button.setIcon(icon);
        return button;
```

}

Here is the snapshot of the UI.[image]

Answer (score 2):

After lot of trial and error finally fixed the problem with below snippet

```
    horizontalLayout.setExpandRatio(headerLbl, 1f);
    horizontalLayout.setExpandRatio(filler1, 2f);
    horizontalLayout.setExpandRatio(addNoteHeaderBtn, 0.15f);
```

Here is the snapshot of the fix.
[image]

If you don’t want empty space, but want one or more components to take all the leftover space. You need to set such a component to 100% size and use setExpandRatio()

Comment: Do you really need that third line setting the expand ratio on the button?

Comment: Yup, that fixed my issue.

Comment: Using filler element is actually not nice. Instead you should consider using setComponenAlignment: https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.5/8.5.1/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractOrderedLayout.html#setComponentAlignment-com.vaadin.ui.Component-com.vaadin.ui.Alignment-

horizontalLayout.setExpandRatio(headerLbl, Alignment.MIDDLE_LEFT);
horizontalLayout.setExpandRatio(addNoteHeaderBtn, Alignment.MIDDLE_RIGHT);